# Platform independent leak/cyclic dependency detection of objects

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management

Sometime back I came across a bug where a particular object was leaking but it was very hard to identify the root cause. I knew that it was due to a cyclic dependency (which usually indicates a bug in the design), but couldn't get a clue where the design went wrong.

I wrote a small utility class [view on github](https://github.com/bashrc-real/Codearchive/tree/master/cpp/leakTracker) to help me out; 
It inserts instrumentation in the code at compile time and keeps tracks of the object allocation.

I am aware of some awesome tools that help in tracking issues like these (valgrind is my favorite), but I was looking for something cross-platform and more verbose. In the current shape I feel my solution as more of a diagnostic utility rather than a detection utility. Please provide feedback on this/suggestions on other solutions that solve the same problem.

Known problems with the current solution:

1. I am keeping a static object to track the list of active objects. The lifetime of static objects is not well defined(?). There can be a possible timing issue in the way I am acquiring a lock to guard a singleton object
2. It doesn't gives the stack where the leaking object was allocated. I couldn't find a portable solution to do this.
3. The static members need to redefined in an implementation file if the solution is to be used for different compilation units.

Alternatives considered:

- Overloading new and delete could have achieved a similar result, advantage being they wouldn't be as intrusive as this solution. But for large projects (which was my case) if you want to track only a handful of classes new and delete may be an overkill
- Using RTTI to track the ownership and the identity of the leaking objects. But some projects do not enable RTTI (leads to code bloat, easy to make bad design decisions)

Source code:

```
#pragma once
// include guard
#ifndef __ALLOCATION_TRACKER__
#define __ALLOCATION_TRACKER__


#ifdef TRACK_MEMORY

#include <mutex>
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

// static members that need to be defined in implementation
//  std::map<void*, const char*> m_objectCollection;
//  std::mutex m_collectionLock;
class AllocMapper{
    public:
        static AllocMapper* GetAllocMapper(){
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_lock);
            if (!m_allocObject){
                m_allocObject.reset(new AllocMapper());
            }
            return m_allocObject.get();
        }

        void AddObjectCreated(void *ptr, const char* objectName){
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_collectionLock);
            auto ret = m_objectCollection.emplace(ptr, objectName);
            assert(ret.second);
        }

        void RemoveObjectDeleted(void *ptr){
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_collectionLock);
            auto deleted = m_objectCollection.erase(ptr);
            assert(deleted);
        }

        ~AllocMapper(){
            if (!m_objectCollection.empty()){
                std::cout<<"Number of outstanding allocations:"<<m_objectCollection.size()<<std::endl;
                for (const auto &iter : m_objectCollection){
                    std::cout<<iter.first<<" "<<iter.second<<std::endl;
                }
                #ifdef _MSC_VER
                    DebugBreak();
                #else
                    assert(false);
                #endif
            }
        }
    private:
        AllocMapper() {}
        AllocMapper(AllocMapper const&) = delete;
        void operator=(AllocMapper const&) = delete;
        std::map<void*, const char*> m_objectCollection;
        std::mutex m_collectionLock;

        static std::unique_ptr<AllocMapper> m_allocObject;
        static std::mutex m_lock;
};

class AllocTracker {
    public: 
        AllocTracker(const char *objectName, void *parentAddr){
            m_parentPointer = parentAddr;
            AllocMapper::GetAllocMapper()->AddObjectCreated(parentAddr, objectName);
        }
        ~AllocTracker(){
            AllocMapper::GetAllocMapper()->RemoveObjectDeleted(m_parentPointer);
        }
    private:
        void *m_parentPointer;
};
#define DECLARE_ALLOC() AllocTracker m_allocTrackerObj{__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, reinterpret_cast<void*>(this)}
#define DECLARE_ALLOC_NAME(x) AllocTracker m_allocTrackerObj{x, reinterpret_cast<void*>(this)}

#else
#define DECLARE_ALLOC()
#define DECLARE_ALLOC_NAME(x)
#endif

#endif // include guard
```

Comment: For those skimming the question: the code pretty much works, it's a bug detector. The code itself doesn't contain significant bugs to the best of OP's knowledge.